# Eliminar un objeto de un array almacenado en localStorage con React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Estoy intentando eliminar un objeto de un array almacenado en localStorage con `localStorage.removeItem()`. He intentado realizar dicha acción de la siguiente forma:

Principalmente al añadir un ítem, tomo su id y lo envío a la función `deleteProduct()`, donde realiza un mapeo de los productos y retorna el objeto que incluye el id especificado, para posteriormente eliminarlo.

```
    const Cart = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [item, setItem] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')))
    }, [])

    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        products.map((product) => {
            if(products.includes(id)) {
                return product
            }
            setItem(product)
            console.log(item)
            localStorage.removeItem('data', item)
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Container type={'min'}>
                <SVGContainer way={'way1'}>
                    <Way1 />
                </SVGContainer>
                <Header />
                <SubContainer type={'min'}>
                    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
                </SubContainer>
            </Container>

            <ContainerAll>
                <ProductsList>
                    {products.length > 0 && products.map((product) => {
                        return(
                            <Item key={product.id}>
                                <div>
                                    {/* <img src={product.picture} alt=""/> */}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                                    <p>{product.description}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>Min price: ${product.minPrice}</p>
                                    <p>Max price: ${product.maxPrice}</p>
                                    <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(product.id)}>Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </Item>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </ProductsList>
            </ContainerAll>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece haber un problema con la configuración de la función callback del método `map`, se puede usar el método `filter` para eliminar el `id` de `products`:

```
let newData = products.filter(item => item.id !== id)
```

Luego, con el nuevo array que regresa `filter`, se carga un nuevo valor para `data` en `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Finalmente se carga un nuevo valor para el estado `products`:

```
setProducts(newData)
```

Quedaría algo así:

```
const onSelected = (id) => {

    let newData = products.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    console.log("newData",newData);
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(newData));
    setProducts(newData)

    /*
    products.map((product) => {
        if(products.includes(id)) {
            return product
        }
        setItem(product)
        console.log(item)
        localStorage.removeItem('data', item)
    })*/
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó

Answer (score 1):

No es buena idea depender del valor de un estado recién seteado para obtener un dato que se necesita usar inmediatamente después.

Ese estado está desactualizado y en todo caso no eliminaría el dato correcto del `localStorage`.

Yo le haría varios cambios a tu código e intentaría hacer todo de una forma totalmente distinta.

En primer lugar, haría un cambio en el nombre que usas para hacer el `.map` de los productos. Ya que al llamarse `products` al igual que el estado, podría generar conflictos.

Así que le cambiaría el nombre a `productRendering`.

```
{products.length > 0 && products.map((productRendering) => {
                    return(
                        <Item key={productRendering.id}>

...
```

Luego cambiaría el argumento que le envías a la función para eliminar.

En vez de solo el Id, le enviaría todo el objeto.

```
<button onClick={() => deleteProduct(productRendering)}>Delete</button>
```

Ahora con ese dato, en la función para eliminar, en vez de eliminar el objeto directamente del `localStorage` lo eliminaría del array que tiene los productos así:

```
const deleteProduct = (productRendering) => {
      let index  = products.indexOf(productRendering)
      products.splice(index, 1)
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(products))
      setProducts(products)
    }
}
```

Lo que hago ahí sería buscar el índice que tiene el objeto a eliminar dentro del array que está en el estado `products`.

Con ese índice, mediante `.splice` elimino el objeto del array.

Después, actualizo el `localStorage` con el nuevo array actualizado.

Y finalmente actualizo el estado como corresponde con el `setProducts()` para que los cambios se reflejen en el DOM.

Haciendo las cosas de esa manera, el estado `item` y su función `setItem` ya no serían necesarios.

Con todas esas modificaciones, el código completo quedaría así:

```
    const Cart = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')))
    }, [])

    const deleteProduct = (productRendering) => {
        let index  = products.indexOf(productRendering)
        products.splice(index, 1)
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(products))
        setProducts(products)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Container type={'min'}>
                <SVGContainer way={'way1'}>
                    <Way1 />
                </SVGContainer>
                <Header />
                <SubContainer type={'min'}>
                    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
                </SubContainer>
            </Container>

            <ContainerAll>
                <ProductsList>
                    {products.length > 0 && products.map((productRendering) => {
                        return(
                            <Item key={productRendering.id}>
                                <div>
                                    {/* <img src={productRendering.picture} alt=""/> */}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{productRendering.name}</h2>
                                    <p>{productRendering.description}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>Min price: ${productRendering.minPrice}</p>
                                    <p>Max price: ${productRendering.maxPrice}</p>
                                    <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(productRendering)}>Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </Item>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </ProductsList>
            </ContainerAll>
        </>
    );
}

export default Cart;
```